# Laravel 9 Inertiajs Vite not loading assets on Shared hosting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, vite, inertiajs

I have deployed my laravel 9 with Inertia.js & Vite to my shared hosting acccount but screen was blank because vite cannot load assets after running npm run build.

Error thrown by vite

```
Vite manifest not found at: /home/ljsharp1/fmcosmetics.ljsharp.com/public/build/manifest.json
```

How can I fix this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to migrate from vite to mix and it worked fine on the shared server. If it is a bad idea, please give your suggestion. Thanks.